# Vue JS: Show loader initially and hide it after getting response

Tags: vue.js

I want to show loader initially but after the response I want to hide it. I have following code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Document :loading="loading">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Document from "./components/Document";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    };
  },
  components: {
    Document
  },
  methods:{
    function(){
        let response = await Axios.get(`this-is-url`, {});
        if (response.data == null) {
          return;
        } else {
          this.loading = false
        }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The loader will be placed in the document component like below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
        <b-spinner type="grow" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Document",
  props: {
    loading: null
  },
};
</script>
```

I am writing function in App component because this will come from emit.

Comment: to show or hide an element you use v-if: `<b-spinner v-if="loading" ...>`. your problem is not quite clear

Answer (score 0):

i think by changing the value of loading to false at the response it will hide the Document component.

```
if (response.data == null) {
      this.loading= false;
    }
```

Comment: No need for an `if` statement since the result is the same in both branches.